# No option to print line numbers in gedit

Tags: printing, gedit, menu

I want to print line numbers from gedit, I know how to view them, of course. A previous answer to a question some years ago claimed that the option existed. But on my machine that option seems to have vanished: there is no top bar, no file tab etc. And why is it called 'text editor' rather than 'gedit'? I'm using 20.04.

If there were options then presumably I could also get it to show syntax colouring? There appears to be no proper option to set the language, though I did once find something, but can't find it again.

It is a really simple editor, which is what I want, but these are really simple requirements, and I am stumped.

To summarise: how do I show an option to print line numbers?

Comment: Focus your questions: one specific question at a time on this site.I assume the option for line numbers is your question here.

Comment: 1. why is it called 'text editor' rather than 'gedit'? 2. If there were options then presumably I could also get it to show syntax colouring? 3. how do I show an option to print line numbers? That is **three questions**. Please ask one question at a time. See the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to ask questions in this site.

Answer (score 1):

The option to print line numbers continues to be there where one would expect it, i.e., in the Print dialog. The option is on the Text Editor tab.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The favourite's icon will be in usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop. At least that's where it is in my 20.04 load. You can edit the 'Name' to show anything you want for when the mouse hovers over it.

If you start gedit, then an untitled document will open. The window will open with the tabs 'open' a '+' sign, 'untitled document', 'save' and 3 horizontal lines before the minimise icon. Clicking on the horizontal lines will open a dro-down, which includes preferences that allow the option of displaying line numbers.

Comment: The question is about **printing** line numbers, not displaying.

Comment: It's also about syntax colouring, the top bar, which have nothing to do with printing.

Comment: Thanks for that. There's me thinking that the print dialogue is something to do with the printing subsystem, not the editor. I was expecting to find info about what is sent to the printing system in the preferences page. Much as for the syntax highlighting, which surely is a view option not a print option?